# SurfaceView PixelFormat confusion

Tags: android, transparency, surfaceview, pixelformat

I would appreciate if someone can help me out regarding SurfaceView PixelFormat issue. I know RGBA8888 gives best quality, bit I also need performance. I know RGBA4444 is deprecated, but currently it suits best for my needs quality and performance wise. I have Bitmap with transparency and when I set SurfaceView PixelFormat to RGBA4444, it doesn't work - no error, nothing, Bitmap is simply not there. If I set it to RGBA8888 or TRANSPARENT, everything is ok.

I need RGBA4444 to work - why it doesn't work, what is happening in the background?
There is no other funy things going on in the background - just simple SurfaceView with canvas draw in surfaceCreated method.

Thank you!

P.S. have tried to use all possible Bitmap variations: 32bit, 16bit, 8bit, etc.